# How to add style to a form once someone clicks on it and remove this style when someone clicks away

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

Basically I have a form (id="form") with `background-color: #000000; border: 1px solid #fff;` I want to change it to `background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #000;` once someone clicks on it. I tried using css:focusm but apparently it doesn't work with forms. So is there a jQuery solution to this?
Also it is important that once user clicks away from the form (so when it is not in focus) it should return back to `background-color: #000000; border: 1px solid #fff;`

Comment: have you looked at http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: $('#form').focus(function() { //What do I put here to define new css rules? }); Here is what I figured out so far, I'm not good with jQuery, what do I do to define new css?

Comment: Slightly different : http://jsfiddle.net/A69Fm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that the `form` element can trigger the `focus` event so what you could do is set the color based on `blur` and `focus` event of all elements in the form.

Markup:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
//receives focus
$("input, select").focus(function () {
    $("#myForm").css("background-color", "#fff");

    //OR
    //to swap a class with the CSS defined instead do this
    $("#myForm").addClass("your-class-name");
});

//loses focus
$("input, select").blur(function () {
    $("#myForm").css("background-color", "#000");

    //OR
    //to swap a class with the CSS defined instead do this
    $("#myForm").removeClass("your-class-name");
});
```

the selector `input, select` will select all inputs and drop downs in the page. You can further limit it by prefixing the form id as well if need be.

Comment: worked, one question if I want to add more than one css rule will it look like this?: $("input, select").focus(function () {
    $("#myForm").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#myForm").css("border", "black"); 
});

Comment: Yes, you could do it that way but I would suggest that you create a CSS class and toggle the class instead.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup I've updated the answer to reflect how you can just apply and remove a class which defines all your CSS styles with one line.

Answer (score 2):

another option: http://jsfiddle.net/6TrGg/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".form").mouseover(function(){
        $(".form").removeClass("form").addClass("form2");
        $(".form2").mouseout(function(){
            $(".form2").removeClass("form2").addClass("form");
        });  
    });
});
```